# Create a latex pdf table from Python without pdflatex

Tags: python, latex, python-sphinx, docutils

i want to generate a pdf output created from latex inside a python script.
Since I'ma working under windows with python xy and that i cannot install latex, i would like to know if there is a way to produce a latex output using a **package** from pythonxy (like **sphinx** or **docutils**)
Any suggestions welcomed

Comment: why you can't install latex under windows?

Comment: I think there is no sensible way to interpret TeX source without really being TeX, it is just a too strange language. There might be some PDF-generating libraries in Python, but anything interpreting LaTeX would be almost a full LaTeX distribution.

Comment: We need to know a little bit more about your needs. It looks like you get some LaTeX input describing a table and that you need to turn it into a PDF. Right?  If the LaTeX code is not too much "LaTeXy", do you think you could parse it and convert it to another format which is easily converted to PDF?

Answer (score 2):

[PlasTeX](https://github.com/plastex/plastex) is a Python package that can interpret LaTeX files. Since it does not include a PDF renderer, the easiest way to render to PDF is probably via the [DocBook renderer](http://tiarno.github.io/plastex/plastex/sect0022.html). I don't think there are any DocBook renderers for Python though.

A pure-python solution would be to write a plasTeX (or DocBook) frontend for [RinohType](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RinohType) (I'm the author of RinohType).